# How to parse each asp .net fileupload element?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, uploadify, multiple-file-upload

I am using [this article](http://bobcravens.com/2011/03/upload-multiple-files-with-progress-using-uploadify/) to upload multiple files using Uploadify. My page has multiple fileupload asp controls. These controls also get created when you click on "add button". What I want now is to upload all the files selected in these controls and upload it to the server.

**HTML page**:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
    <title>jQuery Upload multiple files in asp.net</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <link href="uploadify/uploadify.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="uploadify/jquery.uploadify.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#file_upload").uploadify({
                'swf': 'uploadify/uploadify.swf',
                'uploader': 'Handler.ashx',
                'cancelImg': 'uploadify/cancel.png',
                'buttonText': 'Select Files',
                'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
                'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png',
                'multi': true,
                'auto': false
            });


            $("#upload").click(function () { $('#file_upload').uploadify('upload','*'); });
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        
<a id="upload" >Upload File</a> 


        <asp:FileUpload ID="file_upload1" runat="server" />
        <asp:FileUpload ID="File_upload2" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>`
```

I know how to do the upload with single selection but I don't know how to call Uploadify when I have multiple file upload asp .net controls. How can I proceed?

Comment: Uploadify support multiple files on a single upload control. Why do you have multiple upload controls?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie It's just a requirement. If you take a look at the link there is a section "Multiple Files With Multiple HTML Input ". I want something like that but with asp controls

Comment: Strange requirements. I want multiple files, but I want separate buttons to select them? The uploadify plugins will interfere with each other as they would normally all target the same server service for the actual upload. To get any more help you need to show your entire page/HTML etc as it will be guesswork otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to instantiate multiple instances of the plugin, then fire them all when upload is clicked:

e.g. target a class added to the upload controls instead:

```
<asp:FileUpload CssClass="file_upload" ID="file_upload1" runat="server" />
<asp:FileUpload CssClass="file_upload" ID="File_upload2" runat="server" />
```

and attach the plugin with:

```
$(".file_upload").uploadify({
```

or just target all inputs of `type="file"` (as suggested below):

```
$("input[type=file]").uploadify({
```

Then change the click to start them all uploading:

```
$("#upload").click(function () { 
      $('.file_upload').each(function(){
           $(this).uploadify('upload','*'); 
      });
});
```

*I make no guarantees this will work as you will be sending a load of files to the server at once, but give it a shot.*

Comment: I don't think asp controls take class as an attribute.

Comment: @A Beginner: `CssClass=""`! :) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass(v=vs.110).aspx Answer updated with this info. Give it a try.

Comment: You can avoid the need for `CssClass="file_upload"` by changing the selector to `$("input[type=file]")`

Comment: @Daniel Cook: A lot slower than a class selector, but that is not relevant here, so true. Yes, you can. Added to answer :)

Comment: It's not working. When I click on upload link nothing happens

Comment: That does not tell me much. Any number of failures will stop it working. Reduce it to just the first with `$("input[type=file]:first")` in the selectors and see if it works. Otherwise alert the selector result length and see that you actually match elements.